# Can BCNF decomposition preserve all functional dependencies given F = {AB -> E, BC -> G, C-> BG, CD->A, EC->D, G->CH}?

Tags: database, relational-database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies, bcnf

> Given `F = {AB -> E, BC -> G, C-> BG, CD->A, EC->D, G->CH}`, perform a BCNF decomposition and check whether it preserves all functional dependencies.

The minimal cover is `R = {AB->E,C->B,C->G,CD->A,EC->D,G->C,G->H}`

I performed on `R` a BCNF decomposition(it is a must to perform on the minimal cover) and I stayed with two dependencies of which one is preserved and one isn't preserved. In the answers they tell me that all of the dependencies are preserved. Can please anyone confirm this?

Comment: What is the problem? If there is a decomposition that preserves all FDs, so what? As you give it the problem is to find a BCNF decomposition and check whether it preserves all FDs. You did that. Is the assignment *different* from what you say? Is it to find a decomposition that preserves all FDs if there is one, or what? PS What are the attributes of the relation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**AB**E, **C**BG, **CD**A, **CE**D, **G**CH  are in BCNF and loosless join and dependency preserving.  relation keys are in **bold**

There is always a possibility to add a new relation for preserving a dependency as long as this new relation is in BCNF.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from the canonical cover, we can see that the determinant of `A B → E` is not a superkey and so `R` can be replaced by:

```
R1 < (A B E) , { A B → E } >
```

and:

```
R2 < (A B C D G H) ,
{ G → C
G → H
C → B
C → G
C D → A
A B C → D } >
```

In R2 the determinant of `G → C` is not a superkey and so `R2` can be replaced by:

```
R3 < (B C G H) ,
{ G → C
G → H
C → B
C → G } >
```

and:

```
R4 < (A D G) ,
{ D G → A
A G → D } >
```

So, the final decomposition is:

```
R1 < (A B E) ,
{ A B → E } >

R3 < (B C G H) ,
{ G → C
G → H
C → B
C → G } >

R4 < (A D G) ,
{ D G → A
A G → D } >
```

and the dependency:

```
{ C E → D }
```

is not preserved.

Comment: Thank you sir. I hope now they raise my points, because I checked that like 3 times during the exam with 2 different algorithms and the dependencies weren't preserved.

Comment: My teacher told me that the dependencies aren't preserved. Are you sure about it?

Comment: CE -> D is not preserved, so we can say that the dependencies are not preserved by the decomposition.

Comment: I mean he told my the dependencies are preserved*. and I still can't get that. and he doesn't want to raise the points to the students.. he persists that they do preserve. :/

Comment: How does giving this decomposition show that there is no dependency-preserving decomposition?